# Changing the access options when compiling JavaDoc using ant

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I want JavaDoc to render all members of classes that aren't public. So a previous SO question tells me I need to change the access options:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#public

But I can't figure out how to do this when using an ant build.xml

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in [the documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html) - I suspect you want

```
access="private"
```

as an attribute within the `javadoc` element.